# Parsing file name in Bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed, grep

I am writing a script currently, and I am having an issue getting the correct substring value.

The file name is Package-amd64-3.0.11.deb. I needed to extract "3.0.11" from this name however when I used substring, I do not know how to properly predict the number of characters (would break if I had a file with version # 3.0.9)

```
fName="/etc/deb/Package-amd64-3.0.11.deb"
version="${fName:23:29}"
```

Comment: `[[ "/etc/deb/Package-amd64-3.0.11.deb" =~ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"`, or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps. First, strip everything up to and including the final `-`:

```
version=${fName##*-}
```

Next, strip the extension:

```
version=${version%.deb}
```

That should be reasonably resilient against changes in the package name, and can be modified easily if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to remove the known suffix and prefix:

```
fName="/etc/deb/Package-amd64-3.0.11.deb"
version="${fName%.deb}"
version="${version##*-}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
fName="/etc/deb/Package-amd64-3.0.11.deb"
sed -E 's/.*-(.+)\.[^.]*$/\1/' <<< "$fName"

3.0.11
```

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F- '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/, ""); print $NF}' <<< "$fName"

3.0.11
```